# What are some of the most extreme physiological effects associated with PTSD?

Tags: psychosomatic-illness

As I understand it, PTSD is primarily a psychological disorder. However some websites claim there are physiological responses, such as vomiting, hyperventilation, and even loss of consciousness. I'm aware that such responses can be attributed to fear, but am weary of unreliable sources. I would like to understand how much of this is fact vs fabrication.

~~~~~ Question ~~~~~

What are some of the most extreme physiological responses ( if at all ) that PTSD can elicit in its suffers?